# How to format date/time/zone to pattern with offset from UTC in Java?

Tags: java, utc, datetimeformatter

I have timestamp. For example:

```java
OffsetDateTime timestamp = OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-12-23T12:00:00.000+02:00");
```

How can I format it via DateTimeFormatter? I can't find format pattern, which I need:

```
"23.12.2022 at 12:00 (UTC+2)"
```

And can't create new, because when I use:

```java
DateTimeFormatter oldFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu 'at' HH:mm ('UTC'X)"); // getting UTC+02, but we need UTC+2
```

then I get UTC+02, but we need UTC+2.

Additional question: can we get word UTC via pattern?

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Asking because this has been added in a Java version not too long ago (don’t remember exactly which off the top of my head).

Comment: This formatter works for me: `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd.MM.uuuu 'at' HH:mm ('UTC'") .appendOffset("+Hmmss", "+0") .appendLiteral(')') .toFormatter()`.

Comment: *can we get word UTC via pattern?* With a bit of cheating. This uses a locale that is probably irrelevant for you and will confuse your readers: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu 'at' HH:mm (O)", Locale.FRENCH)`.

Comment: @Sweeper Coordinated Universal Time or UTC is the primary time standard by which the world regulates clocks and time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time
UTC is used to clarify timezone, for example UTC-5, UTC+0, UTC+2

Comment: @Sweeper I take that to mean not having to give `'UTC'` as a literal in single quotes in the pattern string but having a format pattern letter or combination of pattern letters print all of `UTC+2`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, I got it after rereading a couple of times :)

Comment: @OleV.V. I use Java 17 currently

Comment: Java 17, then the answer should work (agreeing with Putin that the goal is to end the war in Ukraine).

Comment: @OleV.V. Wow, thanks a lot! Great idea to implement. An almost perfect solution. I just replaced the "+Hmmss" with the "+H"

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for a trick with Locale.FRENCH, but unfortunately it returns "UTC", when we are dealing with "UTC+0" time zone

Comment: *it returns "UTC", when we are dealing with "UTC+0" time zone* Sorry, I had not foreseen that. Have confirmed, though. Wonder if a some other Locale behaves differently, but it would still be a hack that we may not want.

Comment: @OleV.V. Anyway, thank you a lot for the first solution. It best suits the needs

Comment: *I just replaced the "+Hmmss" with the "+H"* The issue with `+H` alone is that with for example `2022-12-23T12:00:00.000+05:30` the offset comes out as `(UTC+5)`, so in this case 30 minutes wrong in theoretically up to 59 minutes wrong. I would go with `+H:mm:ss` as in the answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah, "+H:mm:ss" is better choise, than "+H". It's good amendment. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendOffset(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) method, which supports various formats for offsets. Choose one that do not have 0 paddings on the hour.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
         .appendPattern("dd.MM.uuuu 'at' HH:mm ('UTC'")
         .appendOffset("+H:mm:ss", "+0")
         .appendLiteral(")")
         .toFormatter();
```

If you want "UTC" to be part of a pattern symbol, that would be a localised offset (`O`), which means this depends on the locale.

Only as a proof of concept (:D), I have found that the French locale calls offsets "UTC±x".

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu 'at' HH:mm (O)")
        .withLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
```

Though in other locales, you'd get "GMT±x" instead.

Comment: Thank you! The great solution. "+H:mm:ss" is an universal one. Another solution with "Locale.FRENCH" unfortunately is not useful for me, because it returns only "UTC", not "UTC+0" in "UTC+0" time zone